# Print space position in a string

Tags: vb6

I am asked to substitute the space (" ") character in a string but for every line that I read from input the space position may change. Following an example:

```
"John Doe"
"Jay Leno"
"Michael Jordan"
```

as you can see the space position between name and surname changes, so I have to read which position the space is and substitute with a '*' symbol. Any ideas?
I really don't know where to start.

Following another post here i used the *split()* method to separate the two parts of the string in an array because it's useful for my task but after that I'm lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

long time since I've used VB6 but how about

```
Replace("John Doe", " ", "*")
```

OK, how about

```
TRF_DIVIDE = InStr(1, "John Doe", " ", CompareMethod.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to achieve your goal -

finalStringObject = oldStringObject.replace(" ","*");

This will work in both scala and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do

```
Dim result As String = Replace("forename surname, " ", "*")
```

Comment: Nope, I need to know the position of the space because I have to pass this value to another variable called TRF_DIVIDE that must contain a number indicating in wich position the space is located

Answer (score 0):

This will work if all names have a single space:

```
Dim l_Pos As Long
Dim l_Name As String

l_Name = "John Doe" ' Sample Name

l_Pos = Instr(l_Name, " ")   ' Get character index of first space
Mid$(l_Name, l_Pos, 1) = "*"   ' Replace space with *
```